# Alt-tab crashes gnome classic desktop (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, compiz, freeze

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 12.04 and noticed alt-tab wasn't working. I followed some advice and installed compizconfig settings manager, wherein I checked Application Switcher. Then alt-tab worked, but sometimes (lately, every time) it crashes the desktop. I'm using gnome classic (which by the way I have not been able to set as the default... I have to select it every time).

After hitting alt-tab, the screen freezes, and the mouse can be moved only briefly every few seconds, and clicking anywhere doesn't seem to do anything. Some parts of the screen become a bit distorted. One time it recovered, but then crashed again as soon as I clicked on the time in the upper-right corner.

Any idea how to fix this? Where can I look in the log files? Perhaps I can uninstall compizconfig (after all, it does come with a warning that it can wreck your system) but then how can I get alt-tab to work?

Many Thanks.

EDIT: I guess not many people have had this issue. I suspect it's a problem with my graphics card - perhaps it doesn't like the fancy effect involved with alt-tab window-switching. So a revision to my question would be: how do I enable alt-tab to switch windows for me in the simplest, safest, non-fancy way? Can I do it without compizconfig?

Comment: Uninstalling CCSM won't help anything, because it's just a convenient way to edit a config file somewhere.

Comment: Related on ubuntu 21.10: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/1956299

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in case others with the same issue come across this, the solution was to disable the application switcher in compiz, and enable the **static** application switcher. The shift switcher also works nicely.

More info:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/971051

I noticed that if I used the gnome classic (no effects) desktop, a basic form of alt-tab worked fine, which was what I wanted, but I want some of the effects in the regular gnome classic desktop. For some reason my computer couldn't handle the fancy Application Switcher option.

Answer (score 2):

Select "Static Application Switcher" at the bottom of the config window in compizconfig settings manager instead of "Application Switcher" in the same window.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> should then work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar behaviour in 14.04: freezing screen and need to log-in after alt-tab. not always, but frequently enough to be annoying. Seems to be solved now:

- Installed compiz config
- Under 'desktop', swithed off the Ubuntu Unity Plugin,
- directly re-enabled this plugin

Compiz now complained about a conflict ('Show desktop plug-in', if I rembember well) and proposed to resolve this, which offer I gladly accepted.

et voila.

jvdw

Answer (score 0):

Not to directly answer your question; but if you log in using Gnome classic and then log out without crashing the desktop. You should, in theory, then default to Gnome classic for subsequent log ins.  I suspect that by crashing out, the log on settings are not being saved.  On my computers it defaulted to Gnome classic after the first time I logged out.

Comment: Good idea, but even when I rebooted normally it didn't save my settings.