# Ubuntu 14.04 crashes on Alt+Tab

Tags: 14.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

Not always. Sometimes. When I click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it freezes and then log off. After that I need to login again. It really annoys. I [found this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296294/alt-tab-crashes-gnome-classic-desktop-12-04) but answer did not worked for me. It's already checked "Static Application Switcher". It's on gnome classic desktop.

How to solve this very annoying problem?

#### UPDATE

Command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Result:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Command:

```
uname-a
```

Result:

```
3.16.0-46-generic #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 16:27:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Information you provided about your system along with your question is not enough to guess what is the actual problem.. So please provide information about your kernel ,graphics .. Processor etc..

Comment: Please.. Post uname -a commands output here.  So that would be helpful to identify the cause of problem you are facing . I am using 14.04 for 1 yr .. So far .. I didn't encounter any problem related to alt tab.. So please give information about your system as much as you can..

Comment: Post lsb_release -a and uname -a command s output here ..

Comment: @shivaraj, updated

Comment: Please specify graphics ,processor..system model and make also..

Comment: Can't reproduce it on 18.04 anymore