# Launcher and Alt+Tab crashes desktop

Tags: shortcut-keys, launcher

Whenever I put the mouse cursor on the launcher the desktop crashes and then comes back without closing the processes running. The same happens when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and wait for the windows to appear, but not when I press it quickly enough to change to the previous window.

Can someone help me, please? It's really annoying. I was using my notebook today and it was alright.

EDIT: when I boot on recovery mode, the issue disappears, but when reboot normally it comes back

Comment: Have you tried this solution?: [Alt-tab crashes gnome classic desktop (12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296294/alt-tab-crashes-gnome-classic-desktop-12-04)

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. Switched off application switcher and checked the static application switcher, but it keeps the same.

Comment: Then, it could be a graphics driver problem, try searching for that issue, for example [Ubuntu 16.04 graphics crashes with Intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767429/ubuntu-16-04-graphics-crashes-with-intel-graphics)

Comment: It worked! I reinstalled the X drives as showed in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763672/16-04-how-to-purge-intel-default-drivers-reinstall-intel-graphic-drivers). Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear that, I'm marking this question as duplicate of the solution that worked. =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 - How To Purge Intel Default Drivers & Reinstall Intel Graphic Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763672/16-04-how-to-purge-intel-default-drivers-reinstall-intel-graphic-drivers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 graphics crashes with Intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767429/ubuntu-16-04-graphics-crashes-with-intel-graphics)